# How to Bind Validation to TimePicker (AvalonControlsLibrary)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to bind custom validation to a TimePicker custom controll but the bellow code says that "Canot add content to an object type of TimePicker.".

```
<Controls:TimePicker Name="TimePickerEndTime"
                      Grid.Row="2"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      SelectedHour="11" 
                      SelectedMinute="20" 
                      SelectedSecond="0"
                         >
        <Binding Path="EndTime" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <Validators:MyCustomTimepickerValidation ErrorMessage="{DynamicResource NumberValidatorMesage}"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </Controls:TimePicker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `Binding` in `SelectedTime` tag:

```
<Controls:TimePicker Name="TimePickerEndTime"
                  Grid.Row="2"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  SelectedHour="11" 
                  SelectedMinute="20" 
                  SelectedSecond="0"
                     >
     <Controls:TimePicker.SelectedTime>
        <Binding Path="EndTime" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <Validators:MyCustomTimepickerValidation ErrorMessage="{DynamicResource NumberValidatorMesage}"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
     </Controls:TimePicker.SelectedTime>
</Controls:TimePicker>
```

*Full tutorial how to create `ValidationRules` to the `TimePicker`.*

1) Create style to show the error message:

```
<Style x:Key="timePickerInError" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:TimePicker}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                  Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                      Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

2) Create custom class which inherits from `ValidationRule`:

```
public class TimeRangeRule : ValidationRule
{
    private TimeSpan _min;
    private TimeSpan _max;

    public TimeRangeRule()
    {          
    }

    public TimeSpan Min
    {
        get { return _min; }
        set { _min = value; }
    }

    public TimeSpan Max
    {
        get { return _max; }
        set { _max = value; }
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            TimeSpan time = (TimeSpan)value;

            if ((time < Min) || (time > Max))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false,
                  "Please enter the time in the range: " + Min + " - " + Max + ".");
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult(true, null);
            }
        }
        else
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

3) Write appropriate binding with Style and ValidationRules:

```
<Controls:TimePicker Name="TimePickerEndTime"                               
          Style="{StaticResource timePickerInError}" >
    <Controls:TimePicker.SelectedTime>
        <Binding Path="EndTime" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <Validators:TimeRangeRule Min="10:00:00" Max="15:00:00"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </Controls:TimePicker.SelectedTime>
</Controls:TimePicker>
```

Comment: I put but in this way can't use my custom validator.     SelectedTime="{Binding  Path=start_time,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>      I can't find out how can I set validationrule inline.

Comment: @LóriNóda check my answer again.

Comment: Thanks @kmatyaszek the problem was that  I put Binding inside Timepicker tag instead of  <Controls:TimePicker.SelectedTime>. Thanks again. I don't know why i didn't saw in your first answer.